# How can I split descriptors (0/1 and stderr) into 2 different files while pinging in linux

Tags: linux, bash, ip

I have a list of ip addresses in .txt format

```
162.243.217.39
170.175.178.13
235.169.86.84
218.820.241.164
104.89.61.87
254.217.220.124
```

It is necessary to ping IP addresses and sort those that give an error 2 (stderr) and a working result into two files.

I think it should look something like this:

```
while IFS= read -r ip; do
    if ping -c4 $ip == 0 ||ping -c4 $ip == 1
    then >> correct.txt
    else >> error.txt
done < ip_list.txt
```

But I don't understand how to do it correctly in terms of syntax

Comment: please update the question to show a couple `ping` results ... one success, one error ... and the results you want to see in your two output files (`correct.txt` and `error.txt`)

Comment: Redirections take effect *before* the command runs, where you want to decide where to write the output *after* the command has run and the output is already written. I suggest a temporary file.

Comment: @trincot, sorry, i`d already solved it by that time and and without refreshing the page I`d delete it. Restored the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- want to capture the stdout and stderr from all `ping` calls into files `correct.txt` and `error.txt`, respectively
- need to test/respond-to the return code of the `ping` calls

Generally speaking:

```
ping ....  >> correct.txt 2>> error.txt
```

**NOTE:** *no* space between `2` and `>>`

Examples:

```
$ ping -c2 ddd.ddd.com >> correct.txt 2>> error.txt
$ echo $?
1

$ ping -c2 yahoo.com >> correct.txt 2>> error.txt
$ echo $?
0

$ head correct.txt error.txt
==> correct.txt <==
PING yahoo.com (98.137.11.164): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 98.137.11.164: icmp_seq=0 ttl=48 time=281.624 ms
64 bytes from 98.137.11.164: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=239.202 ms
--- yahoo.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 239.202/260.413/281.624/21.211 ms

==> error.txt <==
ping: unknown host
```

The `echo $?` output shows we still have access to the return code so if you need to perform other actions in your script then this should suffice:

```
while IFS= read -r ip; do
    if ping -c4 $ip >> correct.txt 2>> error.txt
    then
        do some other stuff
    else
        do some other stuff
    fi
done < ip_list.txt
```